# How To Add Cursor Pointer To Button Overlay on File Input

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/adambene/pen/xRWrXN

```html
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Upload a file</button>
  <input type="file" name="myfile" />
</div>
```

```css
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

In this example, I want to add cursor:pointer css property, which turns the mouse pointer to hand symbol when hovering over it. However, I am not able to achieve the same. I tried adding the property to all three css elements in all combinations, but that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You could add font-size to your input and it should work. Pay attention to font-size: 20px;

```
.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it disables the file upload functionality from clicking in that area.

Comment: oh I'm sorry missed that.... I have updated answer :)

Comment: that works in Firefox, but for some reason not in Chrome or Brave

EDIT: It does work on partial region though (on the right side of the button). Maybe I need to figure out the right value for font-size.

Comment: The button part of the input does not change to pointer, but the text part [no file chosen] does. You know of any way to make that button part disappear, or smaller?

Comment: Make input font-size: 0; and .btn font-size: 20px with cusor:pointer; perhaps?

Comment: https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

The issue is that the cursor: pointer property does not apply to the 'Browse' or 'Choose File' buttons in input. It works in Firefox, because the other part of the element is on the left, and the property does apply there. But in Chrome it is on the right, so the left part does not change to pointer. I'm figuring out how to get it working, your answer definitely helped me in the right direction.